# How does the view count of questions work?

Tags: support

For example, if you refresh the page 2 times that means 2 views?
What I'm asking is whether the view count reflects reality or if it is inaccurately increased (like for example Beast Lair)

Comment: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/259147)

Comment: Thank you XD. I delete the question I guess?

Comment: No need, if somebody else would become curious enough, they can stumble upon it, and don't have to ask a new question for it ;)

Comment: The very last comment says unique per IP per 15 minute interval. So after 15 minutes refreshing works?

Comment: I'm gonna rephrase it. I've been watching one question once a day for the last 9 days and the count view increased exactly by 9. Was it me?

Comment: very likely yes

Comment: Well, I guess then it does inflate numbers a bit but it's mostly accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a question [over at meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728) which goes into a lot of details. But here’s the gist of it:

1. Every question page has a counter link embedded:
   `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3590653/ivc/[Random code]`
2. There is a throttle mechanism in action to prevent hitting F5 transforming into an inflated view count:

   - for anonymous users, `IP + question number` is saved
   - for registered users, `user number + question number?` is saved.

   Each of those as a pair and in an expiring cache entry which will expire after some fifteen minutes. If the cache entry still exists, refreshing the page will *not* generate a new hit. Otherwise it will.

Source for all of this is [the accepted answer to the question linked above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187).